# Proper way to prepend array using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I like prepend an array to an array.
To append, I write it like this.

```
Foo.update({ _id: id }, { $push: { bars: { $each: bars } } }, {upsert:true}, function(err){

});
```

Is there a proper way to prepend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, use `position: 0`

```js
db.Foo.update(
   { _id: id },
   {
     $push: {
        bars: {
           $each: bars,
           $position: 0
        }
     }
   }
)
```

Look at the docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/